# Mysql select (search) query with list of items

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
recipe_tbl
id | name   | ingredients
--------------------
1  | Banku  | corn dough, cassava dough, okra, tomato, onion, pepper, garden eggs
2  | Jollof | rice, tomato, pepper, onion, spice
3  | fufui  | cassava, okra, plantain
```

and I want to select a recipe that has ingredient that matches any of the list provided by the use.

For instance if the user search for "coco, butter, okra" they should get item with id 1 and 3 since they both contain "OKRA" and if they search for "pepper, cream, curry" they should get items with ID 1 and 2 since they contains "PEPPER".

I will ge glad if anyone can help me, thanks

Comment: since the tables not normalized you may want to use the mySQL function [Find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) add the results of each OR statement together and if it's > 0 return it.  but don't ask it to be fast..  Normalized data would perform faster as it would be able to use indexes.  your other option is to consider [full text searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) `match`

Answer (score 0):

Take $userInput = "coco, butter, okra"
Using the Like setence brings everyone with those names in each row
just like you wanted

```
SELECT * FROM recipe_tbl
WHERE ingredients like "%$userInput%"
```

Comment: One issue with this method is that it would only find the exact userInput in the example "coco, butter, okra" as the resulting query would be `LIKE "%coco, butter, okra%". Another idea would be to split this into an array and include each as an OR

Answer (score 0):

You can build a select statement in php using the `like` operator. Separate each of the different search parameters in php. I am assuming you were looking for distinct `id` and not duplicates.

```
<?php
$arr = array("coco", "butter", "okra");
$length = count($arr)
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM recipe_tbl WHERE ingredients LIKE "
for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
    if($x == 0) $sql .= "'%$arr[$x]%'";
    $sql .= " OR ingredients LIKE '%$arr[$x]%'"
}
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```